# Cannot get if statement to work within for statement

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to programming. I have spent hours trying to get this to work. Basically it's a 20 number roulette game. I have list defined for the numbers chosen(clicked). The for loop should move through the array numberChosen one number at a time matching the random number called var Spuntile. Each time it matches it will add 20 to the winNumber variable. The bets are in $5 increments. Here's the code, it's a little messy at the moment.

```
var numbersChosen = [];
var Black = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20];
var BlackChosen = 0;
var Red = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
var RedChosen = 0;
var winNumber = 0;
var winnings = 0;
var spunTile = 5;
//var spunTile = randomNumber(1,20);
onEvent("nameInput", "input", function () {
    showElement("checkMark");
    showElement("nextButton1");

});



onEvent("nextButton1", "click", function () {
    setProperty("helloText", "text", "Hello, " + getText("nameInput") + "." + " Welcome!" + " This is a virtual casino, choose a table to go to.");
    setScreen("screen2");


});

onEvent("Roulette", "click", function () {
    setScreen("screen3");
});


Tiles.Tiles();




onEvent("Spin", "click", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbersChosen.length; i++) {
        if (numbersChosen[i] === spunTile) {
            winNumber = winNumber + 20;
        }
    }
    winnings = winNumber * 5;
    setProperty("tile" + spunTile, "text-color", "#ffdb00") || setProperty("hiddenText", "text", spunTile);
    setProperty("winText", "text", "You Win: $" + winnings + "!");
    showElement("winText");

    setTimeout(function () {
        hideElement("winText");
    }, 5000);

    //(numbersChosen[i]

});

onEvent("black", "click", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        BlackChosen = BlackChosen + 1;
        setProperty("betsText", "text", "Click on a tile to bet on it and press the spin button to spin the wheel to see if you win!\n" + "\nYour bets:" + numbersChosen);

    }
});

onEvent("red", "click", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        RedChosen = RedChosen + 1;
        setProperty("betsText", "text", "Click on a tile to bet on it and press the spin button to spin the wheel to see if you win!\n" + "\nYour bets:" + numbersChosen);
    }
});





    //numbersChosen[i-1] - spunTile == 0;
    //winNumber = winNumber + 20;}
    //if (numbersChosen[i] - spunTile == 0){
    //if (numbersChosen.includes(spunTile));
```

Here's a screen shot:
[Screen shot in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCUiC.png)

The array is storing numbers selected I added a watch in the debug console and selected 19 numbers, these all showed in the array. The numbersChosen.length returned 19 also. i returns  numbersChosen[i] returns undefined. This is done in code.org which I think is a slightly stripped down version of Javascript. I'll try and attach a screen shot.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the problem you're facing? Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: The array is storing numbers selected I added a watch in the debug console and selected 19 numbers, these all showed in the array. The numbersChosen.length returned 19 also. i returns <not available> numbersChosen[i] returns undefined. This is done in code.org which I think is a slightly stripped down version of Javascript. I'll try and attach a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Please edit the content of this comment into the question.

Comment: I figured out the answer to the problem. The numbers in the array were string format, the if statement queried a whole number as I was using === instead of ==.   ie                     if (numbersChosen[i] === spunTile)   changed to --->   if (numbersChosen[i] == spunTile) - this solved the problem as === compares type and value, == compares value only. It was always returning false as the values didn't match. This is my first time using the forum. I got downvoted and unfortunately the people who downvoted could have been constructive and let me know what they had an issue with.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you updating the numbersChosen array? It will always return length 0. for this the for loop is not working and the if statement is not executing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the library to the question later. This was done on code.org and the library does not show up with the link. I created the library only as it was a project requirement. I updated the comments above with the solution to the problem.